# user report generation by various attributes

Tags: database-design, reporting, jasper-reports, birt

User table contains the following attributes (dateOfBirth, race, gender, ...). We would like to generate a report in the following format.

```
Year Race     All Male Female
2000 Asian    2000 1000 1000
2000 Hispanic 1000 500 500
2001 Asian    1500 700 800
2001 Hispanic 1300 400 900
...
```

Total         5800 2600 3200

Ideally I would like to view different reports filtered by the above parameters (e.g. All Asian Male users in year 2000, All Asian users b/w years 2000-2005, All Hispanic community in 2001). What would be the best way to fetch this data, as I would like to avoid too many hits to the database to construct this data. What framework would be ideal in fetching / representing this data

Comment: I would like to understand some details regarding data generation. How many queries to the database are needed to construct this data. 

Each row in the above case at a minimal would need 2 queries 
[a] to fetch the list of all males in a year (variable parameters are year, race)

So if this list is huge what would be the best way to retreive this data in a optimized fashion. The above example only contains a minimal data set and I would like to add many such parameters in a row, which would increase the queries which need to be fired per row. Is there a better solution to fetch this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give any details about the database back end you will be using, but in general the most efficient way to generate this information will be to process the data aggregation and filtering on the database side with the correct SQL and pass only the result set to your report generator.  For the first example, which appears to be an aggregation of all of the data in the table, the database engine will have to sort and process all of the rows, but you'll be better off doing it there instead of the client.  For queries involving subsets of the data, make sure you're indexed correctly for your queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at Jasper Reports:

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2139263/Jasper-Report-Tutorial

or

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2002/jw-0920-opensourceprofile.html

It's a smart framework to generate reports.

Comment: Thanks for responding, as for as report generation is concerned, I am fine with the option of using Jasper Reports. I have added more information regarding an optimized mechanism to construct the data in each row, if the number of variable parameters is huge.